# SD card emulator

Tags: sd-card

I have one project to do.
I need to transfer photos from camera to PC, i need to use SDcard interface it is SPI i hope ).
Because usb transfer is not in option, so i think that i connect some microcontroller or raspberry pi instead of sdcard and emulate sd card and from microcontroller i somehow send it (via usb or ethernet)to pc. this whole operation (wrom camera to pc) must be realy quick (1-2s) and photos are 2-4Mbyte. Do you have any tips how to do that or what microconroller chose?

scheme:

```
    SPI                     as SD emulator     USB/Ethernet
  |camera|--------------->|microcontroller| ---------------> |PC|
```

thanks for advices and ideas.